# Selenium Docker

Tags: selenium, docker

I am using selenium with dockers in a Debian VM without GUI and I am having problems to get the web elements. If I launch the selenium server as a jar in my machine works like a charm.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to 
    org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

Any ideas? Is it necessary to have a VM with GUI?

Comment: which docker image you are using ?

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Docker-Compose

Comment: from the error, it has nothing to do with docker selenium , it's your java script issue, have you run the same script passed without docker selenium

Comment: docker images used: selenium/hub:3.5.3-astatine and selenium/node-firefox:3.5.3-astatin. The same script passed in machine with a standalone server jar

Comment: What can you see on Hub webpanel? Could you check your sessions?